# IOS 5: to make a "back" button take me to a different view

Tags: xcode4.2

My Login view controller is embedded in the navigation controller. From there I could go with a push segue to a Main view controller.
The Login view controller is also linked with a push segue to a Signup view controller if the user needs to sign up.
Now when the user finished signing up I want to go directly to the Main view and not back to the Login screen. I could do that by firing the segue that takes me to the Main view from the delegate of the Signup.
But now the problem is, the back button in Main takes me back not to Login as I want, but back to Signup. What am I missing here?

So basically I want: L to S, S back to M (skip L), L -> M, M back to L.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use storyboard/segues, so it's hard for me to give concrete solutions, but...

For this type of situation, you probably don't really want the design you suggest.  It's confusing to the user.  If I go forward, I *expect* to be able to go back to the immediate prior view.  What you propose breaks my mental model of a navigation stack.

A better solution, IMHO, would be to keep a push relationship between login and the main view controllers.  For the *unusual* (since it should only be done once) condition of signing up, present the signup view controller modally.  This is an ideal use for modal view controller presentation, requires no changes to your navigation stack, and results in forward-back behavior that is easy for you and is consistent with a mental model of navigation.

(If you want to make things super-easy for the user, automatically push the main view controller onto the stack as soon as the modal signup view controller is dismissed.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Conrad. I'll go with a modal on that one. I thought about that too but I just wanted to keep everything on "push" since it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is [use an unwind Segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them) that takes you back to the main View after login. That way the login View is not on the navigation stack anymore and the back button wont trigger it again.